# Line chart with two scaled Y axis in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi

Hi I want to create line chart with two scaled Y axis in PowerBI.
Can anyone suggest how to implement it? or point to any resources?

Comment: I have just answered similar here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60436889/how-to-have-weekly-and-monthly-data-on-power-bi-dual-axis-chart/60438412#60438412

Answer (score 1):

For this you will need to create a "line and clustered column chart" or a "line and stacked column chart". Put measure one on "column values" field and the other measure on "line values" field. The the two dimensions need to be put on shared axis and column series. Now Go to formatting, enable secondary axis and changes the status of "Align Zeroes" to ON. You are now done with your job.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that the closest you'll get to what you're looking for, "out of the box", is a combined line and column chart. See [this from Microsoft](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-tutorial-customize-x-axis-and-y-axis-properties/) to see how it is done. I did see that a lot of folks have requested the ability to have two Y axes with lines for both on [Microsoft's ideas site for Power BI](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/12490791-add-secondary-axis); so I'm sure Microsoft knows it is wanted.