# How to have weekly and monthly data on Power BI dual axis chart?

Tags: powerbi

I have 2 time series of data, one that is a monthly value and one that is weekly. When I "expand" all down 1 level it kind of does what I want but it doesn't properly show the monthly values.

Is there a way I can have a chart that shows the monthly values (and just months) for one set of data and weekly values for another set of data on the same chart?

Some Sample Data

Month/Yr    Sigma
Oct 2019    5
Nov 2019    5.5
Dec 2019    4.5
Jan 2020    4.75

WeekNum Defects
43      6
44      4
46      5
51      10
1       8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PowerBI visuals work at a specific grain. You can have monthly and weekly series, but they will not "fit" on one visual unless you can build a correlation between the two, for example, rolling your weekly series up to monthly. Then you can show both series on the same monthly axis. If you can't correlate, you will need two charts using "vanilla PowerBI".

There is a [PowerBI feature request](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/7135315-multiple-y-axis-on-a-chart) that you can upvote for a 3 axis chart, please do.

[You can use R to achieve a three axis chart](https://blogs.perficient.com/2018/05/22/multiple-axis-line-chart-in-power-bi/), however you lose ability to control styling through PowerBI themes.

Also, [explore this option on PowerBI.Tips charts](https://powerbi.tips/2019/09/dual-y-axis-line-chart/)

or look in Appsource for 3rd party options, an example below - I am not affiliated with the vendor in the image, nor used their product.

[image]